# schema to copybook mapping - number

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, copybook, wtx

I have a mapping from xml schema(number) to copybook, copybook field is a number PIC S9(03). If my input xml element is 67, it is getting transformed to 06G. If the input is 65, getting transformed to 06E, in copybook. 14 to 01D, 15 to 01E. -14 to 01M, -15 to 01N. We are not getting the logic how this is trnsformed like this. We would need to perform a similar operation in the response, that is converting 01N to -15, using xml(not sure how we can do this)

**EDIT**

if the copybook(PICS9 03) contains (f1 f6 c4 - in hex), in xml it should be converted to 164, c stands for positive. However I see my xml element as 14R, which is the ascii display for f1 f6 c4. How should I define my xml element? Currently it is defined as integer.

**EDIT**

Another option - Is it possible using xslt to transform an xml element which has "14R" to the number +164, same example in the above

Comment: When you are asking an XML/XSLT question, please, provide the source XML, The wanted result and describe the requirements for the transformation. All this is missing from your question. Please, edit and improve.

Comment: Thanks all. I apologize, as the question was confusing and also, Petru has provided the info that we needed, which we have to read and further investigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F1 F6 C4 points to an IBM EBCDIC encoding. With S9(03), the numbers are actually shown in display format (the code for the character '1' is 0xF1, similar to how in ASCII '1' is 0x31 ). The twist is in the S which means signed; take a look at this [link](http://www.groupsrv.com/computers/about681628.html), search for the word "nibble" and you'll get your answer.

Comment: yeah. So how should I define my xml element in the wtx mapping to get 1 from F0 C1. Another option I think of is say my xml element is having "14R"as the value, is it possible using xslt to convert this xml element to number 164? check the example in my question?Also based on this alternative, i am edting my question/tag

Comment: I am a bit confused now, since you bring in XSLT... try reading this, maybe it'll help: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14728841

Comment: @PetruGardea: How would a negative number be represented (say -164)?

Comment: Considering PIC S9(3): -164, using IBM-037 will be encoded as F1 F6 D4 (i.e. characters 1 6 M); 164, for the same, will be encoded F1 F6 C4 (i.e. characters 1 6 D). Try this link, http://www.3480-3590-data-conversion.com/article-signed-fields.html, skip all the way to the bottom, Note 3.